# Developing Android Application w/ Existing App Engine Application

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I have existing appengine application. I'm planning to develop android application with that existing app. I can only find examples on development of android app w/ new appengine application. Any reference for developing android app for existing appengine project?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about it. You have to add some sort of an API that your mobile apps can use and return data in an easily parsaeble format such as JSON or XML. You have think about whether you need authentication and how to do it (Google accounts are integrated in Android, but you need extra permissions to use them). Then you access them from Android using HttpClient or HTTPUrlConnection.

The 'new' way to do it would be to use Goggle Cloud Endpoints which takes care of authentication and generates an Android client for you automatically. However it is still in 
'trusted beta', so you might not be able to use it.

http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/